# MySQL query too slow, 70k rows 12 sec

Tags: php, mysql, query-optimization

This query runs for 12+ seconds on VPS. It joins 3 tables. Only first one "topcics" has about 70k rows, others are about 20 and "post_cc" about 1500.

```
SELECT topics.*, employee.username, accounts.ac_name, accounts.ac_mail
FROM topics
INNER JOIN employee ON employee.id_user = topics.id_owner 
INNER JOIN accounts ON accounts.id_account = topics.id_account 
WHERE topics.status  IN  ('1','3') AND ( topics.id_owner IN (12, 5) OR topics.id_post IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT(id_post) FROM post_cc WHERE id_employee IN (12, 5) ) )
ORDER BY topics.creationdate DESC LIMIT 0,25
```

I have already tried (without any improvement) to remove subquery and first "employee" join. If I remove "accounts" join, query runs under 0.1 sec, but all tables data are needed for sorting purpose during paging.

Explain:

```
+----+--------------------+------------+-----------------+-----------------------+---------+---------+-----------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table      | type            | possible_keys         | key     | key_len | ref             | rows  | Extra                                        |
+----+--------------------+------------+-----------------+-----------------------+---------+---------+-----------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | topics     | ALL             | id_owner,id_account   | NULL    | NULL    | NULL            | 75069 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | accounts   | ALL             | PRIMARY               | NULL    | NULL    | NULL            |     5 | Using where; Using join buffer               |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | employee   | eq_ref          | PRIMARY               | PRIMARY | 3       | topics.st_owner |     1 | Using where                                  |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | post_cc    | unique_subquery | PRIMARY               | PRIMARY | 8       | func,const      |     1 | Using index; Using where                     |
+----+--------------------+------------+-----------------+-----------------------+---------+---------+-----------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
```

I have added suggested keys as index, it improved time for 2 sec., but it's still too slow.

Shortened tables:

```
topics
+--------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id_post            | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| id_account         | int(10) unsigned    | YES  | MUL | 0       |                |
| mail               | varchar(256)        | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| from_name          | varchar(512)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| title              | varchar(512)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| content            | text                | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| id_owner           | int(10) unsigned    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| creationdate       | datetime            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

employee
+---------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type                  | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id_employee         | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| id_user             | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| id_owner            | tinyint(1)            | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| active              | tinyint(1)            | YES  |     | 1       |                |
| username            | varchar(64)           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| email               | varchar(128)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

accounts
+----------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                      | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id_account                 | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ac_mail                    | int(10) unsigned    | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| ac_name                    | varchar(512)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| last_sync_time             | datetime            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

post_cc
+------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                  | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id_post                | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| id_employee            | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| notifications          | tinyint(3) unsigned | YES  |     | 1       |       |
+------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: +1 for well written, detailed question & shortened tables.

Comment: What if you split it into 2 queries each of which is without `OR` just to see if it helps? My best guess is that in this case it `OR` that is responsible for the issue.

Comment: Add the index with status, id_owner and id_post in same key.

Comment: Added indexes but it didn't help. Replacing inner joins with left joins seems to be working :)
Problem remains if I try to Order by column not in 'From' table. Any idea how to fix that? I have even replaced from/join for accounts table and got works very fast, but not if I do the same for employee table.

Answer (score 2):

One likely suspect is that DEPENDENT SUBQUERY.

MySQL is processing that subquery for each row returned by the outer query (which isn't already filtered out by some other predicate.

To improve performance, consider re-writing that either as a JOIN operation or an EXISTS predicate.

To replace that with a JOIN operation, that will need to be an OUTER JOIN (rather than an INNER JOIN) because of the `OR` in the predicate.

As an example of one way to do that:

```
SELECT topics.*
     , employee.username
     , accounts.ac_name
     , accounts.ac_mail
  FROM topics
  JOIN employee ON employee.id_user = topics.id_owner 
  JOIN accounts ON accounts.id_account = topics.id_account
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT q.id_post
           FROM post_cc q 
          WHERE q.id_employee IN (12, 5) 
       ) p
    ON p.id_post = topics.id_post   
 WHERE topics.status IN ('1','3') 
   AND ( topics.id_owner IN (12, 5) 
       OR p.id_post IS NOT NULL
       )
 ORDER BY topics.creationdate DESC LIMIT 0,25
```

I recommend you run an EXPLAIN on that, and see how that performs.

---

Another option is to consider an EXISTS predicate. Occassinally we can get this to perform better, but often times not.

```
SELECT topics.*
     , employee.username
     , accounts.ac_name
     , accounts.ac_mail
  FROM topics
  JOIN employee ON employee.id_user = topics.id_owner 
  JOIN accounts ON accounts.id_account = topics.id_account
 WHERE topics.status IN ('1','3') 
   AND ( topics.id_owner IN (12, 5) 
       OR EXISTS ( SELECT 1 
                     FROM post_cc q
                    WHERE q.id_employee IN (12, 5)
                      AND q.id_post = topics.id_post
                 )
       )
 ORDER BY topics.creationdate DESC LIMIT 0,25
```

For performance, that's going to almost require a suitable covering index for the subquery in the EXISTS clause, for example:

```
ON post_cc (id_post, id_employee)
```

You can try running an EXPLAIN and see how that performs as well.

---

We see that MySQL isn't using an index on the `topics` table.

We might get MySQL to avoid an expensive "Using filesort" operation if we had an index with a leading column of `creationdate`.

And part of the problem is likely that **OR** in the predicate. We might try re-writing that query as  two separate queries, and combining them with a `UNION ALL` set operation. But if we do that, we'd really like to see an index on `topic` being used (we probably won't improve performance by incurring *two* scans of 70,000 rows.

```
SELECT topics.*
     , employee.username
     , accounts.ac_name
     , accounts.ac_mail
  FROM topics
  JOIN employee ON employee.id_user = topics.id_owner 
  JOIN accounts ON accounts.id_account = topics.id_account
 WHERE topics.status IN ('1','3')
   AND topics.id_owner IN (12, 5)

 UNION ALL

SELECT topics.*
     , employee.username
     , accounts.ac_name
     , accounts.ac_mail
  FROM topics
  JOIN employee ON employee.id_user = topics.id_owner 
  JOIN accounts ON accounts.id_account = topics.id_account
  JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT q.id_post
           FROM post_cc q 
          WHERE q.id_employee IN (12, 5) 
       ) p
    ON p.id_post = topics.id_post  
 WHERE topics.status IN ('1','3')
   AND ( topics.id_owner NOT IN (12, 5) OR topics.id_owner IS NULL )

 ORDER BY 8 DESC LIMIT 0,25
```

With a query of that form, we're more likely to get MySQL use a suitable index on the topics table,

```
... ON topics (id_owner, status)

... ON topics (id_post, status, id_owner)
```

Comment: `EXISTS` in the modern mysql versions should be optimized the same way as a correlated subquery and as a `JOIN`. My bet is that switching to 2 queries with `UNION` to avoid `OR` will be the winner :-)

Comment: @zerkms: the execution plan (produced by the optimizer) _does_ depend on the version of MySQL. And it depends on other factors as well, the null-ability of columns/expressions, cardinality, available indexes. My preference is to try several approaches, and compare predictions with actual results.

Comment: fair point. Still would be curious to see a solution without `OR` efficiency:-)

Comment: I'm curious too, which is why I included an example of that in my question in an edit. (Recent versions of MySQL can still generate suboptimal plans with **`OR`** predicates; and we can often rewrite a query use a `UNION ALL` set operator in place of the `OR`, and sometimes get much better performance.

Comment: Indeed. One minor note: `UNION` not `UNION ALL` (plus I would add `ORDER BY` + `LIMIT` to every query)

Comment: @zerkms: with `UNION` or `UNION ALL` query, only one `ORDER BY` clause  is allowed, and that is at the end of the statement, applies to the entire resultset. And the same goes for LIMIT.  The workarounds are to either use an inline view (MySQL honors ORDER BY and LIMIT within inline views), or to use a `GROUP BY` (with enough columns so that rows are unique, so we don't remove rows.) A `UNION ALL` typically performs better than `UNION`, since it avoids the extra step of removing duplicate rows; a `UNION` operation may remove rows we expect to be returned.

Comment: "A UNION ALL typically performs better than UNION, since it avoids the extra step of removing duplicate rows" --- I understand that. In this case - there might be unexpected duplicates, if a particular row satisfies both conditions. So `UNION` here is just a "must". "MySQL honors ORDER BY and LIMIT within inline views" --- that's it.

Comment: Thanks @spencer7593, I learned something, but it still does not produce results. I don't consider dependent subquery as a main problem, because even if I completely remove it and condition connecting it, it is still about same slow. But when I remove fields from 'accounts' table in select statement and leave dependent subquery as it is, I get results in below 0.1s 
1st example takes even longer, about 16 sec.
2nd example about 12 sec
3rd union example matches my best after adding indexes at 9 seconds, but since this should go in paging function, it still not enough.

MySQL version is 5.5.37

Comment: Looks like the subquery is *independant*, thus equates to a simple list of constants.

Comment: @zerkms: but we can write the query such that it guarantees a given row will be returned by only one of the queries combined with UNION ALL; the query in my answer does that; in the query after the UNION ALL I included a predicate that guarantees that it won't return a row returned by the SELECT before the UNION ALL, so the UNION ALL query will return the same set of rows. My point is that a UNION operation will also remove "duplicate" rows within each set; with a UNION ALL we can reproduce the _same_ resultset, without eliminating or producing duplicates.

Comment: @RandomSeed & @ibiza: you are right; that's an _uncorrelated_ subquery, so that gets run only once; I would have discovered that if I had run the queries against the database myself; but I don't have that database available. @ibiza: sounds like its the JOIN to the `accounts` table that is the culprit; but EXPLAIN is showing an estimate of 5 rows, and is using a full scan and join buffer. If the statistics are off, and it's a large table, then we'd really like to see the PRIMARY index being used, with `eq_ref` join operation.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use left join for post_cc table, and then use condition?

Something like this.

```
SELECT topics.*, 
employee.username, 
accounts.ac_name, 
accounts.ac_mail
FROM topics
INNER JOIN employee ON employee.id_user = topics.id_owner 
INNER JOIN accounts ON accounts.id_account = topics.id_account 
LEFT JOIN post_cc ON id_employee IN (12, 5)
WHERE topics.status  IN  ('1','3') 
AND ( topics.id_owner IN (12, 5) OR topics.id_post IN (post_cc.post_id)
ORDER BY topics.creationdate DESC LIMIT 0,25;
```

Comment: A good suggestion, but note that `id_post` column is not guaranteed to be unique on `post_cc` table, so this query could return more rows than original query (i.e. "duplicates" because of multiple matching rows from `post_cc`.)

Comment: Yes, i was aware of that, but it was just a suggestive query and for an example that can give a direction, not exact solution. However, your answer is thorough, and i completely agree with you. Exact solution would be to use left join with subquery like in your example.

Answer (score 0):

The culprit:

> 75069 (rows) | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort

That's what we need to get rid of.

Possible solution: add an index on `topics.creationdate`.

As a side note, the query also has conditions on `id_post`, `st_owner`, and `status`, therefore a composite index on `topics(creationdate, id_post, st_owner, status)` (or any permutation of the last three columns -- test with your data set) might help even further. However, your query seems to pull most of your table anyways, so I expect a simple index will suffice.